# Reading a file until a match found with python

Tags: python, loops, random

I have been trying this code to loop through randomly until a match found in the lookin.txt file and stop when a match is found with no success as my Python knowledge not that brilliant. Code is working only once but i need it to run continously until it finds a match. I appreciate if someone can direct me in the right direction.

```
        #! /usr/bin/env python
import random
randrange = random.SystemRandom().randrange
z = randrange( 1, 1000)

target_f = open("lookin.txt", 'rb')
read_f = target_f.read()
if z in read_f:
    file = open('found.txt', 'ab')
    file.write(z)
    print "Found ",z
else:
    print "Not found ",z
```

Lookin.txt:

```
453
7
8
56
78
332
```

Comment: _"I need it to run continuously..."_ Perhaps a while loop would be useful.

Comment: lookin.txt has only 6 numbers in it. Your z is a random number between 1 & 1000. You have only a 6/1000 = .6% of finding a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
running=True
while running:
    a=random.randint(1,1000)
    with open ("lookin.txt") as f:
        rl=f.readlines()
        for i in rl:
            if int(i)==a:
                print ("Match found")
                with open("found.txt","w") as t:
                    t.write(str(a))
                    running=False
```

Try this.Also *with open* method is better for file processes. If you want to only one random number, than you can just put the *a* variable outside of *while* loop.

Comment: After more testing your code a lot faster and returns different numbers found in every execution.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use while and change the random number:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
target_f = open("lookin.txt", 'rb')
read_f = target_f.read()
while True:                         # you need while loop here for looping
    randrange = random.SystemRandom().randrange
    z = str(randrange( 1, 1000))
    if z in read_f:
        file = open('found.txt', 'ab')
        file.write(z)
        file.close()
        print "Found ",z
        break      # you can break or do some other stuff
    else:
        print "Not found ",z
```

Comment: I get TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int error with this.

Comment: `if z in read_f:` what are type these variables: of `z` and `read_f` ?? `z` is Integer and `read_f` is string. Code is finding integer variable into string variable. It is work for you?? or I am wrong?

Comment: You should convert `z` Integer type variable in `String` type for that. i.e. `if str(z) in read_f:`

Comment: updated, i haven seen it, i was just embeded the logic, now all good

Comment: @Hackaholic: yes agree. Logic i.e. Algorithm is very important(after requirement gathering) for code.

Answer (score 0):

The "z = randrange(1,1000)" gives you one random number and the rest of your script reads the entire file and tries to match that number against the file.

Instead, enclose place the script into a loop for it to keep trying.

```
import random
randrange = random.SystemRandom().randrange

while True:
    z = randrange( 1, 1000)
    DO YOUR SEARCH HERE
```

The while True will cause your script to run forever so depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you'll need to add an "exit()" someplace for when you want the program to end.

Also, your "if z in read_f" line fails because it expects a string and not the integer value from the random number generator.  Try "if str(z) in read_f:"

Answer (score 0):

1. We can get only integer value from target file(used with statement to read file) and create dictionary which get constant time for key search.
2. Apply while loop to find random number into file i.e. in created dictionary.
3. If random number found in the dictionary then add to found.txt and break code.
4. If not found random number then continue for next random number.

   ```
   import random
   randrange = random.SystemRandom().randrange

   with open("lookin.txt", 'rb') as target_f:
       tmp = [int(i.strip()) for i in target_f.read().split('\n') if i.isdigit() ]
       no_dict  =  dict(zip(tmp, tmp)) 

   while 1:
       z = randrange( 1, 1000)
       if z in no_dict:
           with open('found.txt', 'ab') as target_f:
               target_f.write("\n"+str(z))
           print "Found ",z
           break
       else:
           print "Not found ",z
   ```

**Note:** If target file not contains any integer in between random number range then code will go into **infinite loop**.